# Run javascript after specific seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm adding javascript on my website by this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fileoasis.net/contentlockers/load.php?id=6f29997ae5eebe6d78b97e842d1c3835"></script>
```

Is any solution to make this script will run/load after few seconds after website loaded?

Comment: yes, several...

Comment: Looks like you're new here. Welcome! People are reluctant to help if you don't show what you have tried. Please provide some code of your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a function in the external library, load it as usual, then in your main page code add:

```
 // When the DOM is built...
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // Run the named function after the specified delay
   setTimeout(externalFunctionName, millisecondDelay);  
 });
```

If there is not a named function in that external library, then wrap all the code in that library in a named function and use the technique above.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How to load a script after a few seconds, not how to run some code after a few seconds.

Comment: @Bryan Read between the lines. The reason to load the script after a delay is to defer the execution of its contents. That is what my question answers.

Comment: Not if the script calls the function?

Comment: @Bryan *Is any solution to make this script will run/load after few seconds after website loaded?* This is exactly what my code does. Also, if you mean why can't you direct a comment @ me, that's because it's my answer you are commenting on. There's no need to do that here. You can't direct a comment at the person who's answer you are already commenting on.

Comment: Yes, there is a solution. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/    Thanks, that was confusing me.

Comment: @Bryan [Sigh] The question was not tagged with jQuery. We don't provide answers to questions with technologies that weren't asked for.

Comment: jQuery isn't built with magic? But that's why I didn't answer with a jQuery solution.

Comment: @Bryan [Even more sighing] jQuery is an API written in JavaScript. It requires an additional library download, which modifies the architecture of a site. It's not just something that you should casually "throw in" to make something work. At Stack Overflow, we respond to questions with answers that are based on the questions tags. Just because you see JavaScript, does not mean that JQuery answers are wanted. That's why there is a separate JQuery tag.

Comment: I think you missed my point, but mentioned it in your first sentence. `written in JavaScript` also `that's why I didn't answer with a jQuery solution` . No need to be condescending.

Comment: @Bryan No one is being condescending. I'm explaining to you how Stack Overflow works. JQuery is written in JavaScript, but it is a separate API, period. This is a very simple concept and since you keep pushing back on that along with the concept of what question tags mean, it frankly comes across as you being stubborn. I also don't know what you mean by *`that's why I didn't answer with a jQuery solution`* since you posted a jquery solution here in the comments!

Comment: I understand how stack overflow works. Question not tagged with jQuery, or I would have offered `getScript`. I'm pushing back because you didn't answer the question, and your telling all the people that did that their answers are wrong. Anyways, that's all I have to offer and SO is telling me to avoid extended discussion. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
<script>

setTimeout(function()
{
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "https://www.fileoasis.net/contentlockers/load.php?id=6f29997ae5eebe6d78b97e842d1c3835";
  $("head").append(s);
} , 3000);//3 seconds

</script>
```

Comment: Worth noting, this needs to be last on the page. If it's in the header and the page takes 3 seconds to load, this would be executed immediately on load and not 3 seconds after the page is loaded (like the OP asks for).

Comment: The OP didn't mention jQuery. Additionally $("head").append(s); doesn't  work to load scripts in some browsers.

Comment: While this may intuitively seem like the right answer, it is not. That's because although this will cause the element to be included in the DOM, it won't actually be executed because the DOM will have been already parsed. The only way this answer could work is if the DOM could be re-parsed after the new `script` were injected.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm not sure about that. The 3 second delay is a *minimum* delay to wait while the JS runtime does other work. It is not related to the HTML parser parsing the page. As long as that code were the only code in the page (anywhere on the page), it should run approximately 3 seconds after it is encountered, regardless of what the HTML parser is doing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not 100% sure either. Anyway, it shouldn't really matter considering your first comment, which seems like a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the answers show how to load the script using jQuery.

Using plain JavaScript:

```html
<script>
  function loadScript() {
    console.log('Loading');
    var secondsToWait = 3;

    setTimeout(function() {
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = "https://www.fileoasis.net/contentlockers/load.php?id=6f29997ae5eebe6d78b97e842d1c3835";
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      head.appendChild(s);
    }, secondsToWait * 1000);
  }
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadScript);
</script>
```

You can verify it loads using the newtwork tab in web developer tools.

Google loads their scripts like this:

```html
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
</script>
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
var a=document.createElement("script");
a.async = 1;
a.src = "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js";
var m = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m); //insert the srcipt before the first script on the page.
```

Which, given that a majority of web pages have a `script` tag in their `<head>` tag is the same as using `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild`.

[jQuery loads scripts](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f18ca7bfe0f5e3184bf1ed55daf1668702c5577a/src/ajax/script.js) using the same method of append the created script element to the head tag:

```
var script, callback;
    return {
        send: function( _, complete ) {
            script = jQuery( "<script>" ).prop( {
                charset: s.scriptCharset,
                src: s.url
            } ).on(
                "load error",
                callback = function( evt ) {
                    script.remove();
                    callback = null;
                    if ( evt ) {
                        complete( evt.type === "error" ? 404 : 200, evt.type );
                    }
                }
            );

            // Use native DOM manipulation to avoid our domManip AJAX trickery
            document.head.appendChild( script[ 0 ] );
        },
        abort: function() {
            if ( callback ) {
                callback();
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: While this may intuitively seem like the right answer, it is not. That's because although this will cause the element to be included in the DOM, it won't actually be executed because the DOM will have been already parsed. The only way this answer could work is if the DOM could be re-parsed after the new `script` were injected.

Comment: I use it all of the time, particularly to load jQuery if it isn't on a page.

Comment: You may want to thoroughly test your pages as this is well-known to not work universally.

Comment: Please show me documentation that this doesn't work. You may have this confused with `$('head').append` which doesn't universally work, which is why I added a vanilla javascript way to load the script seeing others where using `jQuery('head').append` to load the script.

Comment: I am not confusing it with JQuery, since I'm not discussing JQuery in this post. There are [hundreds of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamically+added+script+doesn%27t+execute&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS718US718&oq=dyna&aqs=chrome.2.0l2j69i59j69i57j69i60l2.3616j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) out there.

Comment: Just looked at the first 5 results and non of them apply. Most are loading a script using `jQuery.append` or by setting element.innerHTML='<script>` or are trying to do something that isn't supported in a dynamically loaded script.

Comment: Then keep looking because many of them are doing it exactly the way you are.

Comment: The only ones that have an issue when loaded this way use `document.write` after the HTML is parsed and that is invalid regardless of if the script was loaded dynamically or not.

Comment: Look man. I know what I'm talking about and I'm not talking about JQuery or `document.write()`. It's not my job to educate you beyond explaining that you've got a solution that is not reliable. It's your job to investigate.

Comment: I have been a web developer for nearly 20 years and I use the same method that Google uses and jQuery uses in its library. If it wasn't reliable I doubt they would be using it and as you stated I would have loads of problems in the hundreds if not thousands of websites I have developed